# Creating a public variable from another class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop

If you have two classes, class a and class b, could you create a variable in class a from class b?
**main.cpp**

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        A() {}
};

class B {
    public:
        B() {
            test = A();
            test.<variable name> = <variable value>;
        }
};
```

The code above is just an example. It will probably cause an error.

"variable name" doesn't exist in class A. Is there a way to create this variable for class A in the constructor for class B?

Comment: No, a class declaration must be complete at time of declaration. You must use different ways to obtain this behavior.

Comment: Unless you're just asking, because you're curious and not to solve an actual problem, this is likely an XY problem. Why do you want to add this variable? How would you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, C++ is not Javascript. Types are strict and, after you define a type, there's no way to modify it.

You can, however, create a local type in a function:

```
class B {
public:
    B() {
        struct A_extended : A {
            int i;
        };
        auto test = A_extended();
        test.i = 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to provide proper constructors, member variables (and possibly getters).
Or you need to add a setter to a and use `m_a.set_value(42)`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    // constructor for A with a value. 
    // made explicit to avoid implicit type conversions from int to A
    explicit A(int value) : 
        m_value{ value }
    {
    };

    int get_value() const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int value) :
        m_a{ value } // <-- this will pass value on to the constructor of A
    {
    };

    const A& get_A() const noexcept // not good design, for educational purposes only
    {
        return m_a;
    }

private:
    A m_a;
};


int main()
{
    B b{ 42 };

    std::cout << b.get_A().get_value();

    return 0;
}
```